# How to change slightly view in asp page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this asp code:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Text:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescPoint" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />                   
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="button" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="width: 20px; height: 23px;color: #ffffffff; background-color: #ffffffff" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" role="button"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>X:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLon" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtLon" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Y:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLat" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtLat" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Here how it looks in view:

[image]

I need the view like this:

[image]

My question is what do I have to change in asp code to make appearance like in picture above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to ASP, but I think you can just use CSS/html styling principles.

In

```
 <input type="button" value="..." id="ffcolorswtach" style="width: 20px; height: 23px;color: #ffffffff; background-color: #ffffffff" onclick="PickColor(1, false, false)" role="button"/>
```

add this somewhere between the quotes after style=

```
left: 80px; //play with the amount to find what works.
```

If you're unable to get the button close enough, it may be because the textbox has padding or margin around it. Search your css files for a reference to #txtDescPoint and edit the padding/margin attribute if it has one.